# Are priority changes ever not allowed In Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am customising the linux kernel.

In normal Linux, the BH thread priority is set to a constant priority (MAX_USER_RT_PRIO / 2) [1], but I am changing the BH thread priority from a constant priority (MAX_USER_RT_PRIO / 2) to another value in the interrupt handler [2].
Specifically, this priority is changed in __irq_wake_thread().

#code1

```
action->thread->prio = prio_input
```

or 
#code2

```
sched_setscheduler_nocheck(action->thread, SCHED_FIFO, & param_input);
```

But with such a customised kernel, the hardware crashes and reboots two seconds later.

I debugged it and identified #code1, #code2 as the cause, but I don't understand what's wrong.

> what was the error when it crashed?

It simply downed without any pop-ups like error messages. dmesg has no clues.

output of command "last"

```
reboot system boot 4.9.201-rt134 Sun Jul 10 11:24 still running 
him :1 :1 Sun Jul 10 11:21 - crash (00:02) 
reboot system boot 4.9.201-rt134 Fri Dec 31 20:00 still running
```

Are priority changes ever not allowed in Interrupt?

Environment 
Hardware: Jetson nano 
Power mode: 10 W 
Power: 5V4A 
Kernel: linux kernel-4.9 
How to build: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/applying-a-preempt-rt-patch-to-jetpack-4-5-on-jetson-nano/168428/4

[1] In setup_irq_thread() 
[2] In __irq_wake_thread()

Reply for other comments:

> changing that could cause some critical BHs to not run in time and break things.

I change only the priority of a few interrupts(BH), not all interrupts. It is set with care.

Comment: what was the error when it crashed?

Comment: I don't know if priority changes are allowed in interrupt context, but if BHs have a fixed priority set to a certain value there is most likely a reason for it, and changing that could cause some critical BHs to not run in time and break things.